# Root hboot 2.18.0001 without computer (HTC EVO 4G)

Tags: rooting, htc-evo, bootloader

My EVO 4G's charging port is broken and I am trying to gain root access on my device. Is there anyway to do so without using the USB port to connect to the computer?

Answer (score 1):

There is currently no way to do this. The only way to gain root on HBOOT 2.18 is to use the [HTCdev tool](http://htcdev.com/bootloader) to unlock your bootloader which requires a USB cable to work since it uses fastboot commands. Revolutionary and other methods [only support HBOOT versions up to 2.16.0001 on the EVO 4G](http://unrevoked.com/rootwiki/doku.php/public/revolutionary#supported_devices).

Comment: is there a way to roll back my HBOOT to an earlier version that will allow me to gain root without a USB/Computer?

Comment: @moesef: To my knowledge, no. You can't downgrade HBOOT when it's locked, and you can't unlock without a computer.